# base64_encode function not returning a correct value when verified with base64_decode

Tags: php, base64

i stored different values to different variable, convert each using base64_encode then merge them together and echo it; it worked but when i decode it, it didn't give me back the normal initial values/original values. Then i decided to store all values into one variable before decoding and encoding but the problem is still same...pls i need your suggestion
BELOW IS MY CODE:

```
 <?php

$pvars_timestamp;
$pvars_os;
$pvars_ip;
$pvars_place_n;
$pvars_publisher_n;

$pvars_timestamp = "pvars_timestamp=" . rand(1520500000 , 1520599999);
$pvars_os = "&pvars_os=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36";
$pvars_refer = "&pvars_refer=https://www.naijaflavour.com/";
$ip1 = 197;
$ip2 = 210;
$ip3 = rand(0,255);
$ip4 = rand(0,255);

$pvars_ip = "&pvars_ip=" . $ip1."." . $ip2. "." . $ip3. "." .$ip4;
$pvars_place_n = "&pvars_place_n=". 80;
$pvars_publisher_n = "&pvars_publisher_n=" . 57;

$res1 = base64_encode($pvars_timestamp);
$res2 = base64_encode($pvars_os);
$res3 = base64_encode($pvars_refer);
$res4 = base64_encode($pvars_ip);
$res5 = base64_encode($pvars_place_n);
$res6 = base64_encode($pvars_publisher_n);
$dec = $res1 . $res2 . $res3 . $res4 . $res5 . $res6;
$final = base64_decode($dec);
$dec2 = $pvars_timestamp . $pvars_os . $pvars_refer . $pvars_ip . $pvars_place_n . $pvars_publisher_n;
$final2 = base64_decode($dec2);
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
echo $dec;
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
echo $dec2;
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
echo $final;
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
echo $final2;

//echo $pvars_timestamp . $pvars_os . $pvars_refer . $pvars_ip . $pvars_place_n . $pvars_publisher_n;

echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
echo $pvars_timestamp;
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
echo base64_encode($pvars_timestamp);

echo "<br/>";
echo $pvars_os;
echo "<br/>";
echo base64_encode($pvars_os);
echo "<br/>";
echo $pvars_refer;
echo "<br/>";
echo base64_encode($pvars_refer);
echo "<br/>";
echo $pvars_ip;
echo "<br/>";
echo base64_encode($pvars_ip);
echo "<br/>";
echo $pvars_place_n;
echo "<br/>";
echo base64_encode($pvars_place_n);
echo "<br/>";
echo $pvars_publisher_n;
echo "<br/>";
echo base64_encode($pvars_publisher_n);
//echo base64_encode($pvars_timestamp); echo base64_encode($pvars_os); echo base64_encode($pvars_refer); echo base64_encode($pvars_ip); echo base64_encode($pvars_place_n); echo base64_encode($pvars_publisher_n);
?>

<html>
<a href="https://nnu.ng/adsure/click.php?a=33&x=TVRVeU1EVTBNamsyTlMweE9UY3VNakV3TGpJeU5pNHhNdz09&z=27&c=1&adurl=558148&pl=80&plurl=946&pvars=<?php echo base64_encode($pvars_timestamp); echo base64_encode($pvars_os); echo base64_encode($pvars_refer); echo base64_encode($pvars_ip); echo base64_encode($pvars_place_n); echo base64_encode($pvars_publisher_n); ?>">CLICK ME</a>

</html>
```

Comment: You can't merge base64 encoded strings and expect that string to decode. You need to either merge them before encoding or keep the encoded strings separate and decode them one by one.

Comment: Concatenating separate base 64 strings actually does yield a decodable result for short strings, but this absolutely isn't something you should rely on

Comment: @iainn - How short? https://3v4l.org/OGHZB

Comment: @Magnus Erikson if you checked the above code i posted, i also merge them before encoding(using $dec2)  but didnt work still.... i want to append the encoded result into a url i.e <html>
<a href="htttps://site.com/click.php?a=33&x=TVRVeU1EVTBNamsyTlMweE9UY3VNakV3TGpJeU5pNHhNdz09&z=27&c=1&adurl=558148&pl=80&plurl=946&pvars=<?php echo base64_encode($pvars_timestamp); echo base64_encode($pvars_os); echo base64_encode($pvars_refer); echo base64_encode($pvars_ip); echo base64_encode($pvars_place_n); echo base64_encode($pvars_publisher_n); ?>">CLICK ME</a>

</html>

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Actually seems to be more about the content of the strings than the length https://3v4l.org/ZZsGv . I'm sure the reason why is blindingly obvious to someone else. Edit: It'll be dependent on whether or not the encoded strings need padding with `=`.

Comment: Of course not. `$dec2` isn't encoded so running "decode" on it won't work.

Comment: @iainn pls what is your suggestion?

Comment: @iainn - The `=` padding argument seems like a good explanation for why it sometimes work and sometimes not. It's like you said in the first comment, it _can_ work but don't count on it :-)

Comment: Just base64 the concatenated string: `base64_encode('var1=x&var2=y&var3=z&....and so on');` and put the result in the URL. On the other page, get that param and decode it.

Comment: @Mangnus Erikson  $final2 = base64_encode($dec2); - This line encodes it. check again.

Comment: That's not what your code says. First you have: `$dec2 = $pvars_timestamp . $pvars_os ....` and the line after is: `$final2 = base64_decode($dec2);`. It says _"decode"_, not _"encode"_

Comment: @Mangnus Erikson thanks, i will try that and see the result.

Comment: @Mangnus Erikson thank you, i just figured out the error, i have seen that i didn't encode $dec2 and i was trying to decode it.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson  thanks my codes are working fine now